# Doesn't the Schrödinger's cat inside the box cause the probability wave function to collapse long before a human opens the box?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, superposition, wavefunction-collapse, schroedingers-cat

My point is that there is no superposition of dead and alive. The cat will cause the probability function to collapse long before we open the box. What am I missing here? Isn't the cat capable of collapsing the probability function? If not, why?

Comment: I think that was ***exactly*** Schrödinger's point when he proposed this thought experiment. The question he was interested in was: What makes the superposition collapse? Why do cats collapse the superposition and not electrons?

Comment: @PeterShor Have you a reference showing that was his intent ?

Comment: If a cat could collapse the wavefunction, then the contents of a perfectly isolated box containing a cat would not evolve according to the Schrödinger equation. So, the rules of physics would have to be such that if some configurations of atoms happens to form a cat (or some other animal), then the rules for time evolution would be different. But you can't really have different fundamental evolution rules for different states, especially given that in QM you can expand a state in terms of other states, so some generic state could have a component containing a cat.

Comment: @StephenG: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat): "Schrödinger did not wish to promote the idea of dead-and-alive cats as a serious possibility; on the contrary, he intended the example to illustrate the absurdity of the existing view of quantum mechanics." You can also read a [translation of the relevant part](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/epr/schroedinger_cat.pdf) of Schrödinger's original article.

Comment: The cat will collapse the wave function of what? Until a human opens the box, wrt the human, the cat + poison system will be in a superposition of dead cat + poison activated and alive cat + poison not activated. It is really important as to with respect to whom we are talking about the wave function. See Everett's original thesis: https://www-tc.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/manyworlds/pdf/dissertation.pdf. You don't have to buy into the Many Worlds "Interpretation" to appreciate this point. For example, see the introductory section of the linked thesis.

Answer (score 11):

A theorem of von Neumann says that it doesn't make a bit of difference whether you model the cat (or anything else along the causal chain between closing the box and opening it to observe the cat) as capable of collapsing the wave function.  You'll make exactly the same testable predictions no matter where along the way you place the collapse.

(The argument occupies the final chapter of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691028931), but recreating it is not a terribly difficult exercise.)

So feel free to posit that the cat collapses the wave function.  Or to posit that only a human has that power.  And if you prefer one story while your neighbor prefers another, let a thousand flowers bloom.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Many Worlds view, no cat, nor even a human scientist inside the box, will "collapse the wavefunction".  The scientist, the cat, and the radioactive particle are all components of the universal wavefunction, which simply branches when the radioactive particle *both* decays and does not decay.  To an observer outside who can't see inside the box or interact in any way with what is in the box, the scientist *both* dies with  the cat and survives with the cat, until the observer peeks inside the box.  At that point, the outside observer's wavefunction branches because it has become correlated with the wavefunction of all that's inside the box.  The idea that "consciousness" causes wavefunction collapse has no meaning.  The scientist who subjects himself to the cat's fate is conscious (aware) in one branch that he survived; in the other branch he might briefly be conscious/aware that he is dying.

Comment: _The idea that "consciousness" causes wavefunction collapse has no meaning_ I agree with that. I'm just not sure whether the Many Worlds view has enough evidence to be taken as the explanation for this. Is there a proof that, like you said, _no entity collapses the wave function_?

Comment: @EddieBravo *I'm just not sure whether the Many Worlds view has enough evidence to be taken as the explanation for this.* There currently isn't any way to distinguish between many of the interpretations of QM. If your issue comes down to that then it won't be resolved, at least not currently.

Comment: @EddieBravo there are some testable variations of objective collapse triggered by various conditions such as enough mass. So far all observation is consistent with there being no such phenomenon, despite experiments with getting increasingly bigger objects (entire mitochondria) into superpositions.

Comment: @JohnDvorak An superposition experiment with [a cantilever](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/quantum-microphone/) has been successful, but a quick search doesn't reveal any results from a [decade-old proposal to create superposition in viruses](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1469) --- let alone a mitochondrion. Do you have a link to support that? I love being corrected.

Comment: It's been quite some time since I heard about the experiment and I can't find an article about it right now... so I guess shooting fullerenes through a double slit will have to do until I do.

Comment: Although this experiment looks quite interesting @rob: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/quantum-microphone/

Comment: @JohnDvorak That's the cantilever experiment. I think we're finished using these comments to clarify this answer, but a question about the state of the art of macroscopic superstitions might make a good [tag:resource-recommendation] question.

Answer (score 2):

This is why I generally prefer a "mostly subjective" viewpoint of quantum mechanics as it is really, despite looking at all the alternatives, the only one that fits the closest to the mathematics of the theory *as given* with no other adulterations (other ideas like MWI, Bohm, etc. really are "different theories" in that they play with the maths and seem to have a fixation on eliminating and explaining away the collapse concept, and they thus really are "empirically equivalent theories" [except when they're not!]. My thinking has been that we need to take it blunt, at face value, and see where that leads.).

On a subjective account, the wave function belongs to *you*, the one outside of the box. It *models*, *your* information or knowledge about the state of affairs in the box. The transition from "live cat" to "live or dead cat" to "dead cat" starting from the initial state is just showing how your *best knowledge*, *without looking* into the box, that you can predict from that initial state, changes. All we can say about the "superposition" at the in-between point is that it means the *predicted* information about the answer to the question "is the cat alive?" is less than one bit.

That said, the theory *does* force us to admit that there really *is* something "odd" going on "in reality", otherwise it would just be doable with classical mechanics. But that "oddity" is more that the Universe seems to have an information limit that prevents the answers to all questions about a system from *existing* with *perfect information* at *all times*. That is, in some *real* cases, there *really must be* less than one bit of information, say, to some yes/no questions.

Problems identified with the subjectivity of the wave function in literature seem to be hung up on the idea that if you take it as subjective, you are taking it as subjective *with some further assumptions* on what the "real" reality should look like that often amount to sneaking classical mechanics in the back door, instead of letting the maths guide you as to what you can/can't say thereabout - which is that, if we make *no* such further assumptions, except perhaps relativistic causality, then you have to say that however it exists, physical parameters have "limited resolution" - limited, even fractions of a bit of, information.

In particular, the "real" information at the point in between queries ("measurements") must lie somewhere between the absolute maximum, as established by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, and the level given by the Schroedinger equation, which may be somewhat less - the latter being, in effect, what @WillO's answer is one way of saying. There are endless scenarios we can imagine for the in-between that we would not be able to falsify.

As a subject, the cat may be assigned a wave function talking about the information it has regarding the contraption that is going to kill it. Of course, soon after that one "collapses" then there won't be any more wave function any more because this subject, the information-bearer, has been terminated.

Hence, from that point of view, it makes no sense to ask this question as it is posed because the wave function in question models *your* knowledge, not the cat's. The cat can't do anything to that. Well, maybe it can - it lets out one final scream as it dies, you hear that through the box, and update your knowledge accordingly :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96475/discussion-between-s-mcgrew-and-the-sympathizer).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion such an experiment cannot actually be performed because the assumption that a box exists so that the macroscopic states of the objects inside the box is hidden from the exterior is false.

The state of the cat (dead or alive) has observable consequences outside the box, no matter what the material of the box is. For example, the gravitational field of a moving, breathing cat is different from the gravitational field of a dead cat. This will influence the way the objects outside the box move. If an external observer assumes that the cat is alive or in a superposition dead/alive but the cat inside is dead  he will make wrong predictions about the motions of other objects he can observe.

So, in my opinion, the box is an impossible construct that has no consequences on what QM predicts. If the cat dies, it is dead for all observers, everywhere.

Comment: Gravitational field of almost any cluster of particles is different in different states of this cluster, but this doesn't break superposition by itself. See also [Why doesn't gravity act as a measurement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78155/21441)

Comment: I do not think that the discussion you linked addresses my argument. I do not claim that objects "measure themselves" because of gravity. I claim that: 1. Gravity cannot be shielded by any box. 2. The gravitational field outside the box provides information about the mass distribution inside the box. 3. The gravitational field outside the box can be measured (within the limits of the uncertainty principle) using a torsion balance for example. From 1,2,3 it follows that the outside observer knows what is in the box, so he will "collapse" the state just like the observer inside.

Comment: In fact, Motl agreed that " if you measure sufficient information about gravitational waves encoding the position, it will "collapse" but you likely won't". I do not understand why the discussion evolved around gravitational waves. A direct measurement of gravitational field with something like a torsion balance is perfectly doable for a cat-sized object, so, as long as such an instrument is located outside the box there can be no superposition inside. On the other hand any massive object can play the role of the torsion balance, so, I think, such superposition cannot actually exist.

Comment: This objection can be redirected to the fullerenes in the [fullerene diffraction experiment](https://www.univie.ac.at/qfp/research/matterwave/c60/). Each of them has gravitational field depending on the position, yet if the superposition couldn't exist the experiment would fail.

Comment: This experiment, just like the experiment with electrons, is based on the fundamental uncertainty implied by Heisenberg's principle. If you arrange the experiment so that which-slit information can be obtained from the measurement of the gravitational field the interference pattern would vanish. For an object as large as a cat the uncertainty principle is not relevant. Again, my argument only deals with those experiments where the uncertainty is artificially increased by the use of a "box" that is supposed to isolate the system. No box is required for the fullerene experiment.

Comment: You can't just dismiss a thought experiment because it's impossible to perform. Why does the state of a cat have observable consequences outside the box, when the state of an atom does not (otherwise you wouldn't be able to put electrons in superposition). Why exactly is there a difference between cats and atoms? This was what Schroedinger was really trying to get at with his thought experiment.

Comment: Peter Shor, I think you can dismiss a thought experiment if it is impossible to perform in principle. I agree that we can contemplate what measurements can be performed using a galaxy-size particle collider because there is no physical principle that forbids the existence of such a device, even if we may never be able to build it. On the other hand building a box that blocks the gravitational field of a cat from "leaking" out seems, at least in my opinion, impossible in principle. to continue-

Comment: cont: We can put electrons, atoms and even large molecules, such as fullerenes, in superposition because our knowledge about their state is limited by the uncertainty principle. Interference experiments performed on such particles are based on their de-Broglie wavelength. On the other hand the uncertainty principle cannot stop you from detecting the position of the cat with enough accuracy so you can decide that it moves and breaths (as live cats do) or it is immobile on the floor (as expected from a dead cat). The large mass of the cat makes the uncertainty principle irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @Andrei: I don't understand the point of your answer. You seem to be saying that you shouldn't even think about Schrödinger cats, because macroscopic is macroscopic and isn't quantum, and microscopic is microscopic and is quantum, and that this is obvious because gravity. This wasn't obvious to Schrödinger. There's no reason it should have been obvious to the OP. And there's no reason you can't find microscopic cats (or a suitable stand-in for them).

Comment: Peter Shor, I agree all objects are quantum, including cats. I also think it is possible to put a cat in a superposition of two positions. But those positions should be of the order of the de-Broglie's wavelenth associated with the cat, probably much smaller than an atomic nucleus. Placing in cat in a superposition of two postions 1m apart or so is far beyond that. The only reason we should expect such states to exist is based on the assumption that you can isolate the cat so the uncertainty becomes much higher than the one imposed by Heisenberg's principle. I think this assumption is wrong.

Comment: It's totally clear that you cannot put a cat in superposition with itself. I know that. You know that. Schrödinger knew that. The question that Schrödinger was asking with his Gedankenexperiment was: ***why?*** You've given two separate reasons: (1) gravitons, (2) de Broglie wavelength, with very weak supporting arguments. I remain unconvinced by both of them. If these facts are as obvious as you seem to think, you should be able to find supporting references.

Comment: Peter Shor, QM is clear that if the state is measured there is no superposition. I have given you an example of how to measure the postion of a macroscopic object, regardless of it being placed in a box or not. It involves observations of distant objects (say a grain of dust) moving in the gravitational field produced by that object. The measurements will only be limited by the uncertainty principle, right, but this error is irrelevant for macroscopic objects such as cats. Can you give me a reason why my procedure should fail? I did not refer to gravitons, only to classical field of GR.